# Is the use case diagram correct? Tictactoe game

Tags: uml, diagram

I have made this use case diagram of a game called Tictactoe.

Please correct it if it is wrong.

Here is an image of the use case diagram:

[image: Tictactoe use case diagram]

Comment: I think your use case diagram is very abstract. more draw and try question again.

Comment: what is wrong with it?

Comment: I don't know Tictactoe game, so i search this game. It's very simple game, but your diagram is abstract for understand your think. But in this time, i can find wrong thing. I think you must check who won the game after player 1 or player 2 is checking the O or X.

Comment: i dont really understand. Check who won the game after player 1 or player 2 is checking the O or X? I should put player 1 is X and player 2 is O?

Comment: Read this page. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tic-tac-toe

Comment: you mean ill be more detailed about the diagram?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- the difference between players is too small to differ players 1 and 2. There is only one actor - player
- Player does not check who won. This is NOT outer behaviour of the system and that means, it is not a use case.

So, the start use case diagram could be shown as:

[image]

But as we have only one actor, we don't need to show actors at all. And we can group the use cases into subsystems/packages. Maybe you haven't seen such UC diagrams, but in the UML standard 2.5 documentation there such ones, too.

[image]

The next step could be joining the state machine diagrams right here or as standalone diagrams.

Comment: I see, thanks gangnus. Now i understand. Can i contact you in the future for future helps in my 
UML diagrams?

Comment: @spoderman69 You are welcome :-) I am here practically every day and reading new uml questions, too. But the next week I will be torn off from the PC...